# mod-rewrite with missing parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have already looked at several Q&A's but can't find an solution to this challenge.
And I am obviously not an expert in mod rewrite.

I have the following url's:

```
MyUrl/value1/value2/value3/value4
MyUrl/value1//value3/value4
MyUrl/value1//value3/
```

In other words some values can be empty.

I want to redirect to:

```
myphp.php?par1=value1&par2=value2&par3=value3&par4=value4
```

With the redirect I have it only works when none of the values is empty.

```
RewriteRule ^myurl/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ myphp.php?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3&par4=$4 [L]
```

I know I can solve this in PHP. But I'm looking for a mod rewrite solution.

Comment: How does mod_rewrite supposed to know whether a URL is `/value1/value2/value3` or `/value1/value3/value4`? The pattern is identical.

Comment: That not what I am stating. Note the double slashes where the parameter is empty.